# Cakephp 3.0 - Validating Input against data in another model

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm a pretty new to Cakephp 3.0 and I'm quite stuck on data validation, or rather Application Rules.

I have a simple user registration form to create a new user in the table 'users'.  In the user registration form, there is a field for "ticket_number" where the user has to enter a ticket number which must exist in the table tickets.ticket_number, and also tickets.registration_status must be false (that ticket had not had a user registered with it yet).
My tables look like this (simplified:)

users:

```
id | username | password
```

tickets:

```
id | ticket_number | user_id | registration_status
```

In my users model, I have defined (user can have many tickets):

```
    $this->hasMany('Tickets', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
```

In my Tickets model, I have defined (a ticket belongs to a user):

```
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

In the users model, I added a rule to attempt to check whether the entered ticket_number exists in the tickets.ticket_number column:

```
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn
               (['ticket_number'], 'Tickets.ticket_number'));

    return $rules;
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error:  Call to a member function primaryKey() on a non-object
```

I'm very stuck here.  Can anyone advise on the right approach implementing this check?  And then, how to also implement the check to see whether the associated registration_status is 0 (that ticket has not been registered yet).

Thanks in advance for any advice!
--D.

Comment: UPDATE:  I updated my rule to this: `$rules->add($rules->existsIn(['tickets.ticket_number'], 'tickets'));` and the Error goes away, but it seems the check does not succeed.  It does not fail with a ticket number that does not exist.

Comment: still this needs to read $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['tickets.ticket_number'], 'Tickets'));
Capital T on the Tickets, your relation is called like: $this->hasMany('Tickets'); this is what it refers too.

Answer (score 0):

The `existsIn` rule will not solve your problem, as it will not take your additional condition into account (`registration-status`).

You will need to provide a custom rule to accomplish the problem you described.

Regarding your update: The rule will return true - so passing the rule, if your tables are not setup correctly or it cannot find the field you are referencing or your field is nullable, check the source here: http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.ORM.Rule.ExistsIn.html#74-91

Answer (score 0):

OK, after considerable tinkering, I solved the first issue (On the user add form, the user must enter a ticket number which must exist in the table tickets.ticket_number.)

The only way I could get this to work using an existsIn rule in the UsersTable model, was to declare the ticket_number field as the primary key in the initialize method of the TicketsTable model:

```
$this->primaryKey('ticket_number');
```

Then the associations and existsIn rule in the UsersTable model worked.  However, this isn't good as I don't want the primary key in tickets permanently set to ticket_number.  It also doesn't solve my second problem (checking tickets.registration_status is false.)

So I took a different approach and instead used `$this->loadModel('Tickets');` in the add method of my users controller.  Then, I could easily perform the required checks:

```
//Look for this particular ticket
    $ticketCount = $this->Tickets->find()->where(['Tickets.ticket_number' => $ticket_number])->count();
    $this->set(compact('ticketCount'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['ticketCount']);
//If the ticket isn't found, then return with the Flash error
    if (!$ticketCount > 0) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Sorry, but a Ticket with this number could not be found. Please, try again.'));
                   return;
    } //otherwise move on...
```

I then similarly query the registration status of the ticket, and flash a different error back if it is already registered.

After the checks are passed, it goes on to the normal Add User checks and saving.

While this solution isn't as elegant as what I was hoping to do in the Users model with a custom association and rule, it works.

I'm also not convinced it can't be done in the model with a rule.  But for now, this solution works.

Anyway thanks hmic for a response.
DBZ